# gcloud-java datastore performance Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud-java

I am developing multiplayer game backend and I have decided to use Google Container Engine to install my docker image. As datastore, Google Datastore sounds fine but I have run some performance tests over it, it doesn't look promising.

I am connecting Google Datastore from Container Engine over gcloud-java api with private key and retrieving a query result may take approximately 1.5 sec so this is huge response time for me

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I get remote connection.

```
options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
                .projectId(PROJECT_ID)
                .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(
                        this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();

        dataStore = options.service();
```

Comment: Have you tried running the same test in a GCE VM? That would help narrow down whether it is a GKE issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but only in my local machine. I deployed my application and docker container in Google Cloud Compute and this problem is solved. (0.2 seconds for example).

Good luck!